# Z scoring and normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I tackled a question that asked

Given the `mean` and `std dev` for rainfall in a city,

`Mean = 1126mm of rain`

`std Dev. = 355mm of rain`

`What is the probability that a year would have more than 2191mm of rainfall.`

The way I went about this was

[image: formula value-mean/std dev]

Using the `Value - Mean/ Std Dev` formula

I retrieved a Z score from the table in my textbook as `0.0013` as the answer to the calculation was `3.00`. So I interpreted this as, to get a rainfall value of larger than `2191mm` there is a `0.13%` chance as the Z score is `0.0013`.

So my Question is, how would I calculate this for LESS THAN not MORE THAN 2191, do I just calculate like so?

`1 - P` where P is 0.13%?

EDIT: This is confusing for me then, if that is how you calculate it what if you retrieve a negative Z value

If I take 685mm for a graph distributed like so

[image: graph of Ndistribution]

And 685 is clearly towards the left side of the 1126mm mean value.

If i retrieve a negative Z score of `-1.24` using the same formula above to calculate it, do I just use the Z table normally? If so then I get a value of `.1075` and to find out the P of less than `685mm` would be `1-.1075` but that would mean the probability of it being less than `685mm is 0.8925`

It is obvious that it's not `0.8925`.

So I assume that for values less than the mean of  the  given data and you're calculating less than you don't have to do 1-P but if you were calculating the probability of MORE THAN 685mm of rain it would be 1-P. Is this correct thinking or am I going mad?

Regards

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how one would do it.

Comment: Well laid out question.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I added an edit for clarification if possible do you think you could look over it to consolidate my knowledge? Just a bit of confusion is all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dealt with your first question in a comment. The added part about $Z$-scores takes a bit more space.

Suppose you want the probability that the rainfall is $\le 685$. That corresponds to a $Z$-score of $-1.24$. Information for negative values is ordinarily not tabulated. That's because it is easy to find using information about positives.

The probability that $Z\le -1.24$ is equal to the probability that $Z\ge 1.24$. This is because the density function of the standard normal $Z$ is **symmetric** about the horizontal axis. The probability of being in the left tail of points $\le -1.24$ is the same as the probability of being in the right tail of points $\ge 1.24$.

Similarly, $\Pr(Z\ge -1.24)=\Pr(Z\le 1.24)$.

It is best, I think, not to try to memorize formulas. Just be aware of the geometry, and "figure out" what to do each time.  Remember, we can think of it as evaluating areas.

Comment: Thank you very much, excellent answer, cheers